# Xcode 8 Error: Cannot Parse the Debug Map : No such file or directory

Tags: linker-errors, xcode8

I just install the new Xcode 8 over the prior working version 7.
I tried building an existing ObjC app and was rewarded with a persistent linker error:

> ```
>  error: cannot parse the debug map for "/Users/--- 
>  Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sunset3-
>  dejxrzrmfgomxxcrzloplmsozads/Build/Products/Debug-
>  iphonesimulator/Sunset3.app/Sunset3": No such file or directory
> ```

Searching around, the previous fixes did NOT work here:

> ```
> 1) Reboot after install
> 2) Xcode Clean Project
> 3) Turn off bitcode build options
> 4) for good measure, I tried targeting into 9.0, 9.3, 10.0 - no difference in outcome
> 5) Also tried three different simulator targets
> ```

Further assessment of the logs reveals a dup object which was not flagged by the previous IDE:

> ```
> duplicate symbol _sharedPlaceDate in:
> /Users/irampil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sunset3-dejxrzrmfgomxxcrzloplmsozads/Build/Intermediates/Sunset3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sunset3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ViewController.o
> /Users/irampil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sunset3-dejxrzrmfgomxxcrzloplmsozads/Build/Intermediates/Sunset3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sunset3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GraphClass.o
> ```
>
> ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

De novo ObjC projects created in XCode8 compile and link just fine.
Any other thoughts on fixing the duplicated object?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same error. For me it was as simple as deleting a framework and reinstalling it. Not terribly sure why this fixed it, but my guess is that Xcode was looking for the same framework in two different places, so by removing it and adding it back, it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had two classes which each had an instance object with the same name. As it happens, this object is a singleton. I had assumed the instance objects' scopes were mutually exclusive, and indeed it ran fine in Xcode7, but not in 8. Who knew?  Fixed by renaming one of the instance variables